# c++11: Templated wrapper function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, wrapper, functor

I try to create a general wrapper function which takes any function as argument and also their parameters. Just something like the `std::thread` constructor.

My current code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename FUNCTION, typename... ARGS>
void wrapper(FUNCTION&& func, ARGS&&... args)
{
    cout << "WRAPPER: BEFORE" << endl;
    auto res = func(args...);
    cout << "WRAPPER: AFTER" << endl;
    //return res;
}

int dummy(int a, int b)
{
    cout << a << '+' << b << '=' << (a + b) << endl;
    return a + b;
}

int main(void)
{
    dummy(3, 4);
    wrapper(dummy, 3, 4);
}
```

The wrapper function itself works. It calls the given function object (`std::function`, functor or just a "normal" function) with the given arguments. But i also like to return its return value.

This should work with the removed `return`-statement, but unfortunately i dont know how to declare the wrapper functions return type.

I tried many things (e.g. with `decltype`), but nothing worked. My question is now, how i get the following code running?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename FUNCTION, typename... ARGS>
??? wrapper(FUNCTION&& func, ARGS&&... args)
{
    cout << "WRAPPER: BEFORE" << endl;
    auto res = func(args...);
    cout << "WRAPPER: AFTER" << endl;
    return res;
}

int dummy(int a, int b)
{
    cout << a << '+' << b << '=' << (a + b) << endl;
    return a + b;
}

int main(void)
{
    dummy(3, 4);
    cout << "WRAPPERS RES IS: " << wrapper(dummy, 3, 4) << endl;
}
```

I think the code should work, except for the `???`.

Thank you for any ideas

Regards
Kevin

Comment: I didn't know this syntax with the `-> `. Thank you for this. It worked:)!

Comment: You should be passing like this: `func(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of):

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
typename std::result_of<F &&(Args &&...)>::type wrapper(F && f, Args &&... args)
{
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

In C++14 you can use the `result_of_t` alias:

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
std::result_of_t<F &&(Args &&...)> wrapper(F && f, Args &&... args)
{
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Or you can use return type deduction:

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
decltype(auto) wrapper(F && f, Args &&... args)
{
    std::cout << "before\n";
    auto && res = std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::cout << "after\n";
    return res;
}
```

Comment: @Smith_61: Very well.

Comment: This worked:) Thank you very much. Unfortunately i didn't know `result_of`.

Comment: In C++14 you can also forget about `result_of` and friends completely and use return type deduction :)

Comment: What does using `&&` in `F&&(Args&&...)` do btw?

Comment: @0x499602D2: It does what it says on the box. It gives you the same type that is later used in the actual call.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `decltype` with the C++11 auto trailing return type :

```
template<typename FUNCTION, typename... ARGS>
auto wrapper(FUNCTION&& func, ARGS&&... args) -> decltype(func(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...))
```

[**Live demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de9cc92d8d305070)

---

And in **C++14**, simply do :

```
template<typename FUNCTION, typename... ARGS>
decltype(auto) wrapper(FUNCTION&& func, ARGS&&... args)
```

[**Live demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/158fd792b0972671)

Comment: Don't you need the whole `std::forward` shebang for the trailing return type too, lest you end up using the return type from the wrong `func` overload, or something?

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It works great:) Also thanks for the c++14 version. `Kerrek SB` gave a working version first, so i marked his post as accepted. But also thanks to you! (you also got a vote)

Comment: @Praetorian yes we do need the "shebang", updated, thanks for the note.