# How to write a template wrapper method for other class member functions?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, c++17

I try to create a templated wrapper for different functions with different parameters.
The setup is a class `A` with the basic implementation of two methods `foo` and `bar`. Another class `B` shall wrap these methods and add new functionality.

The solution from the following link works very well for non-class functions:
[c++11: Templated wrapper function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495448/c11-templated-wrapper-function)

But if I try to invoke methods from another class I get an error.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    void foo(int x) {
        std::cout << "Foo: " << x << std::endl;
    }

    void bar(int x, float y) {
        std::cout << "Bar: " << x << ", " << y << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    void fooAndMore(int x) {
        foobarWrapper(&A::foo, 1);
    }

    void barAndMore(int x, float y) {
        foobarWrapper(&A::bar, 1, 3.5f);
    }

    template<typename  T, typename... Args>
    void foobarWrapper(T&& func, Args&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "Start!" << std::endl;
        std::forward<T>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        std::cout << "End!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.fooAndMore(1);
    b.barAndMore(2, 3.5f);
}
```

I expect something like that:

```
Start!
Foo: 1
End!
Start!
Bar: 1, 3.5
End!
```

But instead I get:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void B::foobarWrapper<void(__thiscall A::* )(int),int>(T &&,int &&)' being compiled
    with
    [
        T=void (__thiscall A::* )(int)
    ]

error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void B::foobarWrapper<void(__thiscall A::* )(int,float),int,float>(T &&,int &&,float &&)' being compiled
    with
    [
        T=void (__thiscall A::* )(int,float)
    ]
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I have another question related to this topic:
Is it possible to get the name of the passed function?

I tried:
```
        auto funcName = typeid(func).name();
        std::cout << "Functionname: " << funcName << std::endl;
```
Inside the wrapper, but the result is:
Functionname: void (__thiscall A::*)(int)
or
Functionname: void (__thiscall A::*)(int,float)

Any idea to get the name of *?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    void foo(int x) {
        std::cout << "Foo: " << x << std::endl;
    }

    void bar(int x, float y) {
        std::cout << "Bar: " << x << ", " << y << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    void fooAndMore(int x) {
        foobarWrapper(&A::foo, x);
    }

    void barAndMore(int x, float y) {
        foobarWrapper(&A::bar, x, y);
    }

    template<typename  T, typename... Args>
    void foobarWrapper(T func, Args&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "Start!" << std::endl;

        auto caller = std::mem_fn( func); // Newly added lines
        caller( A(), args...);  // Newly added line

        std::cout << "End!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.fooAndMore(1);
    b.barAndMore(2, 3.5f);
}
```

output:

```
Start!
Foo: 1
End!
Start!
Bar: 2, 3.5
End!
```

See this link for more details [std::mem_fn](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't std::mem_fn this before.

Comment: @boss0r Welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest fix is to make the member functions of class `A` to be `static`. 
**([See online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/O0uojhaCaicByH9o))**

```
class A
{
public:
    static void foo(int x) {
    ^^^^^^
        std::cout << "Foo: " << x << std::endl;
    }

    static void bar(int x, float y) {
    ^^^^^^
        std::cout << "Bar: " << x << ", " << y << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Otherwise, you need to pass an instance of class `A` to call its member functions in the `foobarWrapper` function. Using lambdas you can pack them to the callable `func` and pass to the `foobarWrapper`.

**([See online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yNYOlspJ9tEr6Ddm))**

```
class B
{
public:
    void fooAndMore(const A& a_obj, int x) {
        foobarWrapper([&]() { return a_obj.foo(x); });
        //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^Args captured to the lambda
    }

    void barAndMore(const A& a_obj, int x, float y) {
        foobarWrapper([&]() { return a_obj.bar(x, y); });
        //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  Args captured to the lambda
    }

    template<typename  T>
    void foobarWrapper(T&& func)   // no Args needed any more (@credits Jarod42)
    {
        std::cout << "Start!" << std::endl;
        std::forward<T>(func)();   // simply call the func
        std::cout << "End!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.fooAndMore(A{}, 1);       // pass a temporary A object
    b.barAndMore(A{}, 2, 3.5f);
}
```

Comment: Thank your for the fast response. Static isn't an option in my case but I will try to get an instance of the class with the base implementation. Thx :)

Comment: @boss0r I have added the second option in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you again, you helped me a lot :) This on is nice and works perfect!

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes... You are right. I have updated accordingly. Thanks for the suggestion.