# Is it possible to get the name of a function passed to a template?

Tags: c++, templates, rtti, typeid

I try to get the name of a class method on runtime which is passed to a templated class method. I would like to know the name for better trace output.

The question results from the question that I asked before:
[Templated wrapper method for other class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56605952/templated-wrapper-method-for-other-class-methods)

I tried to get the name by adding

```
typeid(func).name()
```

But the result is not really satisfying because the name of the function is always printed as a *, see the examples below.

I also tried different compilers (msvc, gcc) and demangle options (abi::__cxa_demangle), but the result is always more or less the same.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    void foo(int x) {
        std::cout << "Foo: " << x << std::endl;
    }

    void bar(int x, float y) {
        std::cout << "Bar: " << x << ", " << y << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    void fooAndMore(int x) {
        foobarWrapper(&A::foo, x);
    }

    void barAndMore(int x, float y) {
        foobarWrapper(&A::bar, x, y);
    }

    template<typename  T, typename... Args>
    void foobarWrapper(T func, Args&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "Start!" << std::endl;

        auto funcName = typeid(func).name();
        std::cout << "Functionname: " << funcName << std::endl;

        auto caller = std::mem_fn( func);
        caller( A(), args...);

        std::cout << "End!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.fooAndMore(1);
    b.barAndMore(2, 3.5f);
}
```

I expected something like that:

```
Start!
Functionname: void (__thiscall A::foo)(int)
Foo: 1
End!
Start!
Functionname: void (__thiscall A::bar)(int,float)
Bar: 2, 3.5
End!
```

Actual results:

```
Start!
Functionname: void (__thiscall A::*)(int)
Foo: 1
End!
Start!
Functionname: void (__thiscall A::*)(int,float)
Bar: 2, 3.5
End!
```

Is it possible to get the real name of the passed function?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can change the signature to accept another `char const*` parameter as the first parameter, and passing in a C-string literal.  I've used the technique as a breadcrumb on events to find out where they had originated, which was very useful for debugging.

Comment: @Eljay That's the way I doing it at the moment and it seems there is no other option :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `typeid` only does RTTI for polymorphic objects (i.e. objects of class type, with virtual functions). For all other types, it'll just give you information about the static type, in this case a function pointer type. (`typeid` for polymorphic objects leverages the vtable to do its work, but there's no vtable-like thing attached to functions.)

For debugging/tracing of this sort, you'll need to use platform-specific debugging utilities.

Comment: Thank you for the explanination.<br/>
I also tried to explicit initialize the templates like:
`
    template void B::foobarWrapper(void(A::*)(int)&& , int&&);
`
But the compiler says:
`
    error C3190: 'void B::foobarWrapper(void (__thiscall A::* )(int) &&,int &&)' with the provided template arguments is not the explicit instantiation of any member function of 'B'
    error C2945: explicit instantiation does not refer to a template-class specialization
`
Do you have an idea what the problem could be? Thx.